# Qt - QCalendarWidget delete all TextFormats

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I was wondering if there is a way to delete ALL the QTextCharFormat you've created with `QCalendarWidget::setDateTextFormat(...)` because I need such a function to update my whole calendar when a new list of QDates is loaded in.

I hope you can help me and else I'll try to just create a new QCalendarWidget everytime a new list is loaded in.

Thank you!

Comment: If I was able to help you, consider accepting my Answer, so other people will know that this fixed your issue. If not please clarify your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do:

```
QCalendarWidget::setDateTextFormat( QDate() , QTextCharFormat() );
```

will set it back to the standard.

Comment: there is actually no QCalendarWidget::clear( ), but i can use the temporary format yes

Comment: Ok i found out that using a pointer also doesn't work :/ because setDateTextFormat() creates a copy of the QTextCharFormat you give..

Comment: i'll check that later